# How to add a second custom menu in my sidebar when theme only supports one?

Tags: menus

I simply want a second menu in my sidebar to show on all pages.  My theme only supports one custom menu though.  I am using the first custom menu for the top level nav, and I wanted my 2nd custom menu in the sidebar.  I created a second menu and tried adding it using the custom menu widget, however this just adds my first menu, I'm guessing because the theme only supports one menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the code give here in your themes `functions.php` file. and register second nave menu as show here.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary-nav' => "Primary Menu", // file may have this with different name
    'sidebar-nav' => "Sidebar Menu"   //add this line
) );
```

Use custom menu widget to show it up in sidebar. OR
If you want to edit the theme template, then put following code where you want the second menu to appear put follwoing code

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'sidebar-nav'
) );
?>
```

Now you can got to [`Menu Appearance Screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen) to assign items to it.

Answer (score 1):

on your sidebar, if your theme supports widgets, you can add a custom menu widget and use that to load your secondary menu.